# Select part of String in XSLT

Tags: string, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to select part of a String using xslt.

Input :

```
p:endnote_bl1
p:endnote_bl2
p:endnote_bl3
p:endnote_bl4
```

Output Should be :

```
endnote_bl1
endnote_bl2
endnote_bl3
endnote_bl4
```

Can I do this using split or something else? I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace function

```
replace('p:endnote_bl1', '^[^:]*:', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do simply:

```
substring-after($string, ':')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of ways to do this.

**This transformation shows four different solutions**, the first two of which are XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0) solutions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSolution1">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="substring-after"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSolution2">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="substring"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSolution3">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="split"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSolution4">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="replace"/>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vSolution1"/>
    ==================
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vSolution2"/>
    ==================
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vSolution3"/>
    ==================
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vSolution4"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="s/text()" mode="substring-after">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'p:')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="s/text()" mode="substring">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 3)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="s/text()" mode="split">
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ':')[2]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="s/text()" mode="replace">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^.+:', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the XML document below (none was provided!)**:

```
<t>
    <s>p:endnote_bl1</s>
    <s>p:endnote_bl2</s>
    <s>p:endnote_bl3</s>
    <s>p:endnote_bl4</s>
</t>
```

**We get four identical, correct results, each produced by one of the four solutions:**

```
<t>
      <s>endnote_bl1</s>
      <s>endnote_bl2</s>
      <s>endnote_bl3</s>
      <s>endnote_bl4</s>
</t>
    ==================
    <t>
      <s>endnote_bl1</s>
      <s>endnote_bl2</s>
      <s>endnote_bl3</s>
      <s>endnote_bl4</s>
</t>
    ==================
    <t>
      <s>endnote_bl1</s>
      <s>endnote_bl2</s>
      <s>endnote_bl3</s>
      <s>endnote_bl4</s>
</t>
    ==================
    <t>
      <s>endnote_bl1</s>
      <s>endnote_bl2</s>
      <s>endnote_bl3</s>
      <s>endnote_bl4</s>
</t>
```